# Could not load Network Link Conditioner preference pane

Tags: xcode

I installed the latest version of `Hardware IO Tools for Xcode (Oct 2013) on OS X 10.8.5. I installed the "Network Link Conditioner preference pane". I get the following error every time I try to run this tool`Could not load Network Link Conditioner preference pane`
I tried to re-install the package but got the same error. Who knows how to fix the problem?

My Solution:
   I've installed OS X Mavericks and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue as well. Are the October 2013 tools broken?

Comment: @Cliff No, I think Oct 2013 is for Mavericks and onwards.For Mountain Lion use July 2012 package.

Answer (score 14):

As said, use Hardware IO Tool for Xcode - Late July 2012.

Installation steps to be sure that it works:

1. Remove any currently installed Network Link Conditioner preference panes (right-click it in the System Preferences window for the option to delete).
2. Verify that there is no file called `Network Link Conditioner.prefPane` in either `/Library/PreferencePanes/` or `~/Library/PreferencePanes/`; if they're there, remove them by hand.
3. Empty your trash
4. Restart your Mac
5. Then, re-install from the old version mentioned above (from late July 2012).

Having to empty your trash and restart your Mac gives the whole process a nice touch of nostalgia for ex-Windows users, but it really made the difference for me.

Comment: I didn't initially believe the restart part, but the trick did magically work for me.

Comment: Indeed, if you are upgrading from an old version of the Network Link Conditioner preference pane, make sure to remove, restart and reinstall, in that order.

Comment: I'm a little late to the party but simply deleting `Network Link Conditioner.prefPane` from `~/Library/PreferencePanes/` and reinstalling the new one from apple's developer portal did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue. I downloaded the Hardware IO Tool for Xcode - Late July 2012. It installed without any problem on OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: I would like to confirm that using the *Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012* worked for me on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5, whereas the *Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Oct 2013* did not, even though the notes say "Tools in this package support running on OS X Mountain Lion and later"... thanks, @bademi!

Comment: This solved it for me in 10.8.5 @lakenen: try manually deleting `/Library/PreferencePanes/Network Link Conditioner.prefPane` before double-clicking the July 2012 version

Comment: I'm running 10.8.5 / XCode 5.1 and the 2013 package did not work but the Hardware IO Tools for Xcode - Late July 2012 *did* work.

Comment: @lakenen; it gave me trouble too. Emptying my trash and restarting my Mac before attempting to install the older version made it all work though. I posted this as a separate answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed OS X Mavericks and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

try to download an older version of Additional Tools for Xcode
for example:
Xcode 13 -> download Additional Tools for Xcode 12.5
this work for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33036214)